# How can I integrate Bluemix service Conversation, Speech-To-Text and Text-To-Speech in android

Tags: java, android, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

**Bluemix**

I would like to use the Bluemix Conversation services in android application
and add speech input and output to it. There are other apps for Bluemix TTS and STT available. What are options to integrate these 3 functions working android app and which of them are recommended for beginners?

**Android**

I already read documentation bluemix it proivide java-sdk
I integrate java-sdk but here is problem I wanted to send voice request hit the server to give me text but my requirement to **stt----> conversation dialog ----> only tts** sound it like react human. I integrate these three functionality reponse it very more time dely. How can I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not necessary to use  Bluemix, you can  make it by yourself 
follow the link for example
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_text_to_speech.htm

this might be what blumix also does internally, If you are looking for easy coding then its up to you.